# Given a simple undirected graph, how to direct its edges to make it transitive

Tags: directed-graphs

I am currently looking for an algorithm to determine whether we can direct every edge (no adding or deleting edges allowed) so that the graph is transitive (meaning that if (x,y) and (y,z) are edges then so is (x,z)).

One way to do it is to use PQ trees as I had an interaction with a professor and this is what he had to say but we are looking for a faster algorithm. When I try to do it myself, my mind keeps looping back to the PQ-tree technique. Each edge is allowed only one direction (if in the underlying undirected graph {a,b} is an edge then exactly one of (a,b) and (b,a) is an edge).

Perhaps there is one algorithm better in the sense of lower complexity than the PQ-tree approach, but we can't seem to find it in literature. Do we take it that doing a PQ-tree approach is the best way?

The title of this post is the best I could do in the google search bar. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the most popular term is [comparability graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph), you are interested in algorithms for recognizing comparability graphs, so that's what I'd put in the search bar.

Comment: this question is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the thought! This is already the second stackexchange site that I have posted. Am I required to remove the post from both here and the earlier one?